# How to record total distance from starting point to end point while running in android?

Tags: android, distance

I am new to android and I'm creating an app that will record the total distance traveled by the phone once you click the "START" button. For example, you clicked the start button and you start running, there is a label for the total distance that will be updating real time while you are running and the total distance will be recorded from starting point where you clicked the "START" button and to the point where you clicked the "STOP" button.

My question is, what is the best and simplest way to do this? I've already done the request permission for the device location. Base on my research, I am confused on what am I going to use, GPS or accelerometer? Is it possible to record the total distance traveled without internet connection? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is LocationListener so when GPS is updated, display it to screen.Internet connection not needed. I don't thinkg there are things such as accelerometer on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.These are questions only you can answer, but...

1) you can use GPS without internet (and numerous apps calculate position and/or distance traveled without internet connectivity).

2) even tiny uncertainties in acceleration will result in significant positional errors over time (certainly using the sort of acelerometer in a typical android device), so that method is unlikely to be practical or accurate.